# Calculation in C

Tags: c, calculation

I would like to make a simple calculation in C.
Nverthless, there might be a problem in my code with the "resultat"...
Was trying to do the exemple given in OpenClassroom, at the following link : https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/19980-apprenez-a-programmer-en-c/14337-une-bete-de-calcul

Here is my code in Repl.
I think the teacher didn't put everything for it to work properly, so I've tried to modificate it by puting the two first lines : https://repl.it/@LunaShivaya/SuburbanThornyDebugmonitor

Thanks in advance for your ideas :)
Sakura.

Comment: Please post relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: Please make this question self-contained. Links might be given as *supplementary* information.

Comment: Please post code directly in the question as text, not as an external link.  Also make sure your question is in the form of a [mcve] which others can compile and run as it along with input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Here is the correct link for the first program.
Sorry about that : https://repl.it/@LunaShivaya/problem1

Comment: @Sakura Prease review the comments above and understand that we *do not* want click any links to understand what the question is about.

Comment: I thought putting any code would've helped the commentators.
It was suggested in the post area...

Anyway, got it's better to put directly the code and not a link.
I will do this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it inside a main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int resultat = 0;

  resultat = 5 + 3;

  printf("5 + 3 =  %d", resultat);

  return 0;
}
```

Libraries are used to load pre-defined variables and functions. In this case, you are using `printf`, which is pre-defined in the library `stdio.h`.

Comment: Thank you ! It was not that clear for me in the lesson.
I'll check it again (I'm juste a begginer).